# Vagrant + Ansible resolving super slow

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

I created a VM using Vagrant and Ansible and when i try to use it after it is booted i note that it is extremely slow. I'm also using a remote DB in the cloud but it seems not to be the cause of the slow response. By slow response i mean about 5secs to load a page most of the time.

Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    # Set the box name and URL
    config.vm.box = "trusty-server"
    config.vm.box = "skeleton"
    config.vm.box_url = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box"

    # Hostmanager plugin config
    config.hostmanager.enabled           = true
    config.hostmanager.manage_host       = true
    config.hostmanager.ignore_private_ip = false
    config.hostmanager.include_offline   = true


    # Fix TTY problem
    config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"

    # Basic box configuration
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.102"
    config.vm.hostname = "skeleton.ontherocks.dev"
    config.hostmanager.aliases = %w(en.skeleton.ontherocks.dev)
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :mount_options => ['dmode=777', 'fmode=777']

    # Provision using Ansible
    config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
        ansible.playbook = "provisioning/playbook.yml"
    end

    config.vm.provision :hostmanager
end
```

Playbook

```
- hosts: default
  remote_user: vagrant
  sudo: true
  sudo_user: root

  tasks:
    ##
    # Update apt packages
    #
    - name: General | Update apt packages.
      apt: update_cache=yes

    ##
    # Apt package instalation of required software
    #
    - name: General | Install required packages.
      apt: pkg={{ item }} state=present
      with_items:
        - build-essential
        - php5
        - apache2
        - php5-mysql
        - sendmail
        - php5-mcrypt
        - php5-curl
        - php5-gd

    ##
    # Apache2 setup
    #
    - name: Apache | Enable required modules
      action: command a2enmod rewrite vhost_alias

    - name: Apache | Configuration file for our site
      action: template src=templates/etc-apache2-sites-available-website-conf.j2 dest=/etc/apache2/sites-available/website.conf

    - name: Apache | Disable the default site
      action: command a2dissite 000-default

    - name: Apache | Enable our new site
      action: command a2ensite website
      notify:
        - Restart Apache

    - name: PHP | Enable required modules
      action: command php5enmod mcrypt
      notify:
        - Restart Apache

    ##
    # Website setup
    #
    - name: Website | Set up file and directory permissions
      file: path=/vagrant/craft/storage/ mode=0777 recurse=yes state=directory
      sudo: yes

  ##
  # Restart services
  #
  handlers:
    - name: Restart Apache
      service: name=apache2 state=restarted
```

Comment: Which provider are you using, i.e. VirtualBox? Are you serving stuff that would have a lot of disk IO?

Comment: VirtualBox and no, definitely not a lot of disk IO. Host computer is not the issue since this is happening in any computer the VM is being used.

Comment: Try syncing the folder with rsync and tell me if the issue goes away : `  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync"`
`

Comment: Also are you on a Windows machine?

Comment: Host Machine is Ubuntu and so is the VM.

Comment: Try to see if rsync helps, it could be the synced folders.

Comment: Same issues, extremely slow. I was using the :mount_options => ['dmode=777', 'fmode=777'] because i need some folders to be writable.

Comment: seems `config.ssh.shell = "bash -c 'BASH_ENV=/etc/profile exec bash'"` fixs the issue `stdin: is not a tty`. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speed up the shared folder with nfs

```
 config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", :nfs => { :mount_options => ["dmode=777","fmode=777"] }
```

Speed up the vm networking

```
 config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"]        
 end
```

This had a 10-15x networking increase for me.